# How do I query custom object history in SOQL with an inner query?

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to pull the history records of a custom object with an inner query.

Here is the sample:

```
Select Id, Name, (Select NewValue From Custom_Object__History) From Custom_Object__c
```

Based on the documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#i1422454)

This should work.

example in documentation:

```
SELECT Name, customfield__c, (SELECT OldValue, NewValue FROM foo__history)FROM foo__c
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Using the force.com explorer I was able to find the solution.

    Select Id, Name, (Select NewValue From Histories) From Custom_Object__c

Hope this may help anyone else with this issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Child history table name is common and is "histories", 
This SOQL should work :

```
Select Id, Name, (Select NewValue From Histories) From Custom_Object__c
```

Comment: You are life savor. :)