# Checking and querying histories from REST API Query

Tags: soql, query, rest, field-history

I've been reading up on queries via the API. This post here on [histories from custom objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/how-do-i-query-custom-object-history-in-soql-with-an-inner-query) and [how to make sub-queries](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67969/rest-api-retrieving-records-linked-to-a-contact-object) have been very useful.

I'm doing blind iterations through the schema - ie, the code I write needs to grab data on any object and be robust as we add new ones.

Currently it all works but isn't grabbing histories - I figure that's because I need to ask it to query the `My_Custom_Object__History` from each `My_Custom_Object__c`. Ideally though, I want an insight into if a record has a history before I fire my request.

I was looking through the rest explorer to see if there was a `Has_history:true` or `Historible:true` kind of parameter on object describe (everything there seems to end in -able!).

If I could find some indicator I could do something like:

`@s_object.get_history if @s_object.has_history` and save myself futile queries and error handling.

Then... assuming `Histories` is a common name across all objects I could just poll `Select Id, Name, (Select Id From Histories) From Custom_Object__c`

Worst case I guess I just have to do the above line and then ignore if `nil`/`null`

Anyone done anything similar or got any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking my own look through the REST explorer, there isn't an attribute that you get from the sobject describe result, nor from the basic object information result, that tells you if history tracking is enabled on an object. It exists as an attribute in the actual object metadata, but it does not appear to be available through anything in the REST API.

About the only thing that I can think of is to iterate over the Child Relationships that you get from the API call for the sobject  describe result, and look for `Histories` or `<sObject Name here>Histories`.

You do have to take care though, there are at least some sObjects that have more than one child relationship with `Histories` in the name.

Opportunity, for example, has the following child relationships (among others)

- ActivityHistories
- Histories
- OpportunityHistories

Of those, `Histories`, which references the `OpportunityFieldHistory` object, is probably what you want.

I believe that `Opportunity` is an exception, and that the history object for most other objects follows the pattern `<standard sObject Name>History` or `<custom sObject Name>__History`. The child relationship name appears to be simply `Histories` in all cases.

Comment: ... Ima gonna open a support ticket to rename the Histories.Histories to Historiography

Comment: Thanks for addressing this so logically, highlighting the objects to take care of is also very useful. I guess I'm resigned to burning a few more API calls on querying and then doing .count of arrays on history. Would of thought HasHistory would be a great parameter for parents, but `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. Cheers!